# splunk 4.3.3 indexer filtering issue

Tags: splunk

Im having some issues filtering / ignoring some events in splunk on an indexer.

Im running a splunk 4.3.3 indexer on ubuntu 12.04 and its working well receiving inputs from remote syslog hosts and a windows host running splunkforwarder-4.3.3-128297-x86-release

The issue is, Id like to filter out some events. Following a doc here...

Filter windows events on indexer from a universal forwarder
http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/24310/filter-windows-events-on-indexer-from-a-universal-forwarder

I can successfully filter out the security events but for whatever reason the system event 10060 are still comming thru

```
root@box:/home/msbren# cat /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/transforms.conf
[FilterSecurityEvents]

REGEX=(?msi)^EventCode=(4634|4624|4769|515|577)

DEST_KEY=queue

FORMAT=nullQueue


[FilterSystemEvents]

REGEX=^EventCode=10016

DEST_KEY=queue

FORMAT=nullQueue


root@box:/home/msbren# cat /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/props.conf
[WinEventLog:Security]

TRANSFORMS-Filter_Events = FilterSecurityEvents

[WinEventLog:System]

TRANSFORMS-Filter_Events = FilterSystemEvents

root@box:/home/msbren#
```

From what I understand Im doing things correct , so I must be missing something. If anyone has any advice Id be very appreciative.

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

To add on to MHibbins comment, you need to remove the ^ before the EventCode as the EventCode is in the middle of the event.  Check out the splunk Blog post at http://blogs.splunk.com/2012/09/21/the-splunk-app-for-active-directory-and-how-i-tamed-the-security-log/ for a detailed process on this.

Comment: hmm... my understanding (and could be wrong)... the carat symbol would match the start of a string (regardless of it's position). Referencing the example here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html. `^. matches a in abc\ndef. Also matches d in "multi-line" mode.`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest....

Firstly, Splunk have an official forum at SplunkBase, which would be ideal for these questions.

Secondly, looking at the two filters... You are missing the regular expression flags in the system stanza.

i.e. for Security you have `REGEX=(?msi)^EventCode=(4634|4624|4769|515|577)` and for System you have `REGEX=^EventCode=10016`.

I believe this is the issue, as MS events are multiline, you will need the `m` flag for multiline, so at a minimum I would recommend adding changing your System REGEX to `REGEX=(?msi)^EventCode=10016`.

Give this whirl, and let us know how you get on...

MHibbin